# Archlinux laptop overheating

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, cpu

I have a Samsung laptop and installed Archlinux on it. At first everything was fine, I was even surprised at how nice everything was, no driver problems, everything went smooth. I could watch videos and it would barely get hot.

But after an update (with "pacman -Syu"), it started overheating (and getting slower as it starts to overheat). I'm not sure about what update was because I didn't notice it right away. I notice it the most when I'm watching videos but it is always hot and I can't really watch videos anymore because then it gets really slow.

I also installed flash, I'm not sure which one worked, I think it was "chromium-pepper-flash". But I also have "flashplugin" installed.

I don't think CPU frequency scaling utilities are the right solution because it was working before. What are my options? How do I detect what caused the problem?

---

Edit: Added some stats

```
Running chrome with 8 text/js tabs opened (Amazon, stackexchange, wired, ...): 

Average temperature: 75 Celsius degrees
Average %CPU: 10%
Average memory: 43%
```

---

```
Same as above but with a Youtube video in fullscreen:

Average temperature: 93+ Celsius degrees (had to stop before it crashed)
Average %CPU: 80%
Average Memory: 47%
```

Does this mean the problem is with the GPU driver?

Comment: Did you check top?  For assistance, this is the bare minimum required to troubleshoot any performance issue.

Comment: Note that `vmstat` might provide more useful for single line outputs.

Comment: `/var/log/pacman.log` lists the updates.  You may be able to spot the culprit in there.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I added some stats based on "top" and "sensors".

Comment: @garethTheRed Oh interesting. I updated mesa about 9 days ago. Hmm...

Comment: I don't think it would be mesa just because of the YouTube CPU usage (Chromium doesn't come with VAAPI anymore on Arch Linux and uses CPU for decoding irrespective of hardware support.)

Can you check what packages were updated?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU's temperature shouldn't rise that high if the issue was limited to software unless you updated the kernel with disabled frequency scaling options.

If you leave the computer idle for 30 minutes (closing down your browser even if it appears to be doing next to nothing) and the temperature doesn't drop below 70C, you should check the ventilation and clean it up.